# Applinking: Google play Console Domain Ownership not verified

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-play-console, android-deep-link

I am working on my applinking, and everything works fine on `Android version 11`, but doesn't work on `version 12 or above!`

And lately, I've found that my ***`domain ownership is not verified`*** on `Google Play Console (GPC)`. I did copy all the codes from `GPC -> Setup -> App Signing` and `configure` them into my website `assetlinks.json`. Yet, my app isn't getting verified, I did everything I could, but still, the issue remains unmoved.

1. public/.well-known/assetlinks.json

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target" : { 
      "namespace": "android_app", 
      "package_name": "com.(myDomain).(myapp)",      
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["EE:C6:DF..."] 
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target" : { 
      "namespace": "android_app", 
      "package_name": "com.(mydomain).(myApp)",      
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["A9:11:AA..."] 
    }
  }
]
```

2. My Android Manifest

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="(myDomain).com" android:pathPrefix="/view/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Though my codes seem perfect, yet, I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I'm definitely getting issues: My domain ownership not getting verified.